# Dynamically add existing controller into another controller with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

in my app I have a `wrapper` controller that handles some properties dynamically based on `other-controllers` within it. everything works like a charm if the `other-controllers` are present/static on load, but as soon as I'm trying to make them dynamic, they stop working.

It was my understanding that the **$rootScope** is available from everywhere within the `app`, is that not true?

my JS looks like this:

```
  var webApp = angular.module("webApp",[]);

  webApp.controller("ControllerA", function($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.cnt = 0;
    $rootScope.cntPlusPlus = function(){
      $rootScope.cnt++;
    };

    $rootScope.controllerBs = [];
    var template = $(".controller-b").html();
    $scope.addControllerB = function(){
      $rootScope.controllerBs.push(template);
    };
  });

  webApp.controller("ControllerB", function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.cntPlusPlus = function(){
      console.log("overwrite plus plus");
    }
  });
```

Full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/tAcv1F9y7t9q9XsQ1EFL?p=preview

I know that this would be probably better with `directives`, but is there any way to make it work with Controllers?

*thanks for the help*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't try to access the DOM from controller code. Never. It is very bad practice which breaks AngularJS conventions and eventually provides you with bad architecture. This also means you should not create any DOM elements manually from a controller.

   Better to manipulate with the *scope* itself, not with its visual *representation*. You can add new models to scope on your button's click, which will be translated to new elements by `ng-repeat` directive, each with its own controller (remember controllers are instances, not singletons, so that they have separated life cycles).
2. You might want to make use of [`<script type="text/ng-template">`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script) and [`ng-include`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngInclude) here instead of hidden `div`s.
3. Try to avoid using `$rootScope` when possible - it is global state which can be dangerous.

It might look like this then ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rAXYP42usSRdAQ5Js2SM?p=preview)):

HTML:

```
<div class="controller-a" ng-controller="ControllerA">
  Controller A
  <div>
    <button ng-click="cntPlusPlus()">cnt++</button> CNT: {{cnt}}
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addB()">Add B</button>
  <div ng-repeat="B in Bs">
   <div ng-include="'b-template'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="b-template">
  <div ng-controller="ControllerB">this is controller b: <button ng-click="cntPlusPlus()">cnt++</button></div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
  var webApp = angular.module("webApp",[]);
  
  webApp.controller("ControllerA", function($scope){
    $scope.cnt = 0;
    $scope.cntPlusPlus = function(){
      $scope.cnt++;
    };
    
    $scope.Bs = [];
    $scope.addB = function(){
      $scope.Bs.push({});
    };
  });
  
  webApp.controller("ControllerB", function($scope){
    $scope.cntPlusPlus = function(){
      console.log("overwrite plus plus");
      $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.cnt++;  //should be moved to service
    }
  });      
</script>
```